# TinyMCE Table of Contents plugin seems disabled

Tags: reactjs, tinymce, reactstrap, tableofcontents

What I'm trying to do is, add a **Table of contents** plugin to my **TinyMce 5 edior**. I'm using react and also my TinyMCE is in an reactstrap modal. When i try to add other plugins, they work without problem. When i try to add **Table of contents** plugin to the editor, everything looks fine except the table of contents. It is unclickable, i think it is disabled. I checked the html code, there is **aria-diasabled: true** on that item. I'm new in react by the way.

Here is the screenshot of the problem:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRFwq.png

Here is my code:

```
<Editor
                    initialValue="<p>This is the initial content of the editor</p>"
                    init={{
                      height: 500,
                      menubar: "insert file",
                      plugins: [
                        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
                        "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
                        "insertdatetime media table paste code help wordcount",
                        "toc fullpage",
                      ],
                      toolbar:
                        // eslint-disable-next-line no-multi-str
                        "undo redo | formatselect | bold italic backcolor | \
                        alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | \
                        bullist numlist outdent indent | removeformat | help\
                        toc fullpage",
                    }}
                    onEditorChange={this.handleEditorChange}
                  />
```

Any solutions there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you misunderstand what that plugin does.  Per the documentation page:

> The toc plugin will generate a basic Table of Contents and insert it
> into the editor at the current cursor position. Items for the table
> will be taken from the headers found in the content.

If your content has no headings (h1 --> h6) there is no data from which to create the TOC.  If your content has such heading tags the menu option will be available and a TOC will be created based on the content in the editor.